# Python logging StreamHandler causes stack_info to print twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm using Python 3.9 and the logging module.  It seems that when I make use of a QueueHandler and the stack_info feature, the stack trace information prints twice.  Anyone know how to avoid this duplication?

This works correctly without the QueueHandler:

```
import logging
import time

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler ()

lo = logging.getLogger ()
lo.addHandler (stream_handler)

lo.error ("This is an example error", stack_info = True)

time.sleep (1)
```

This includes the stack trace twice, and the only change I made was to insert a QueueHandler/QueueListener:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import queue
import time

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler ()

q = queue.Queue (-1)
queue_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler (q)

lo = logging.getLogger ()
lo.addHandler (queue_handler)

queue_listener = logging.handlers.QueueListener (q, stream_handler)
queue_listener.start ()

lo.error ("This is an example error", stack_info = True)

time.sleep (1)
```

Output with the QueueHandler/QueueListener arrangement is the same as without, except the stack trace appears twice:

```
# ./logtest-q.py
This is an example error
Stack (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jcharles/./logtest-q.py", line 19, in <module>
    lo.error ("This is an example error", stack_info = True)
Stack (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jcharles/./logtest-q.py", line 19, in <module>
    lo.error ("This is an example error", stack_info = True)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it prints the stack info twice, but hopefully you're using that flag for debugging purposes? If you want to print the trace when an exception happens, you can use `logger.exception`.

Comment: Yeah, I have a number of conditions which can be reached multiple ways, so this is to help me understand what I'm looking at.  Interestingly, I have a case where I use the exc_info argument, and that does *not* double-up on the stack trace.  I feel like I may have found a bug in the logging module.